# How to fetch multiple cq pages using Xpath based on page's property

Tags: xpath, aem, query-builder, jcr

I have two cq page and I want to retrive these two using jcr:title property using XPATH. The below query is working fine for single.

```
/jcr:root/content/test//element(*, cq:Page)[((jcr:like(jcr:content/@jcr:title, dell)))]
```

But I want to excuate it for multiple items. I have tried with following option but it is not working

```
/jcr:root/content/test//element(*, cq:Page)[((jcr:like(jcr:content/@jcr:title, [dell,samusng])))]
```

Could anyone help me to write xpath query?

Comment: You may not be able to provide multiple values that way. However you can try `/jcr:root/content/test//element(*, cq:Page) 
[
(jcr:like(jcr:content/@jcr:title, 'dell')
or jcr:like(jcr:content/@jcr:title, 'samsung')) 
]`

Comment: thanks Rakhi!, It works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As rakhi4110 already mentioned in the comment, you can combine multiple where clauses with an or just like in SQL. Though I think you either want exact matches or use `jcr:containts` instead of `jcr:like`.

Exact match:

```
/jcr:root/content/test//element(*, cq:Page) [jcr:content/@jcr:title='dell' or jcr:content/@jcr:title='samsung']
```

Contains:

```
/jcr:root/content/test//element(*, cq:Page) [jcr:contains(jcr:content/@jcr:title, 'dell') or jcr:contains(jcr:content/@jcr:title, 'samsung')]
```

Or if you really want to use `jcr:like` which, as in SQL, uses `%` for wildcard:

```
/jcr:root/content/test//element(*, cq:Page) [jcr:like(jcr:content/@jcr:title, '%dell%') or jcr:like(jcr:content/@jcr:title, '%samsung%')]
```